# After_save in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, callback

I have two models `Person` and `Address` and a join table `Persons::Address` containing (person_id, address_id). If my Person object is p, then I do `p.address_ids` to get an array of address ids of that person.

Now, I have an `after_save` callback which uses `p.address_ids`. Let's say I had p.address_ids = [a,b,c]. I ran these two statements after this.

```
a.address_ids = [a,b,d]

a.save
```

In the after_save callback, if I do `self.address_ids`, I'll get [a,b,d]. I want to make an array A = [a,b,c,d] which should contain the elements of (last array + current array).uniq , what should I do?

`Update :`

In simple words, I want something like `p.address_id_was` (ActiveModel::Dirty) for associations like `p.address_ids'.

Comment: Can you not do `p.address_ids += [a,b,d]`?

Comment: No, my addresses are being updated from somewhere else.

Comment: This question is not very clear. Could you try rephrasing?

Comment: Updated! Please check.

Comment: Its still not clear what you're asking. After you assign the new IDs, you have the new IDs as the value. If you want to to *add* new IDs instead of overwriting them, there's a different syntax for that. If you want to implement `address_id_was`, you can do so with an instance variable and a override of `address_ids=`. Please be more specific about what you want to do, even adding pseudocode of how you'd like it to work.

Comment: Yes, I would like to implement address_ids_was so that I can get the address_ids which were present before the after_save callback ran

Answer (score 0):

It's a many-to-many relationship, and I think you're doing it wrong.

The join table should be called `addresses_people` you can use this migration to generate it:

```
class CreateJoinTableAddressPerson < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_join_table :addresses, :people
    add_index :addresses_people, [:address_id, :person_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

I've put a unique index on the composite key to prevent the same relationship being entered more than once.

Make sure your `Person` class has `has_and_belongs_to_many :addresses` and your `Address` class has `has_and_belongs_to_many :people`

Let's suppose you have a `Person` object `p` and this person has two addresses `a` and `b` you can get the collection of `p`'s addresses by saying `p.addresses` and you can get the collection of people that live at address `a` by saying `a.people`

If you want to add more addresses to `p`

```
p.addresses << c
p.addresses << d
```

if you add an address that is already related to `p` it won't be duplicated, nothing will change.

Comment: I didn't ask this. You understood the question wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

a.address_ids = a.address_ids|[a,b,d]

Comment: I think you are not getting my question. In the after_save callback, a.address_ids is [a,b,d]. I want to get the address_ids which were before getting updated.

Answer (score 0):

what if you store old address_ids in before_save callback, and then use it with new ones to create joined array?

Comment: How will I get the old address_ids in before_save callback, as self.address_ids will be the updated one